# TeamCity - MSBuild incorrect build order

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity

Just trying TeamCity for our applications, however, when we try to build the project it fails as the projects are built out of order, causing a crash and it failing to continue.

I have manually run MSBuild against the solution file and it runs correctly. Is there any extra configuration we could have missed when setting up the server?

Comment: There is not enough information in here to help you. Show us your build step configuration in TeamCity, post some logs from build, etc.

Comment: I have to add I had my configuration incorrect, this was a user error and I was in a little bit of a rush. The output of TeamCity didn't appear to output in the way I expected which helped cause my confusion.